# Issue testing null check using NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I am a junior dev that is new to unit testing. My company uses NUnit and I am trying to test a null check in a service method I created. Any idea what my Assert statement should look like if I am trying to test if `string acctName = ""` ? For some reason `string acctName` is getting compiler error that says

> "The name does not exist in the current context."

**MY METHOD:**

```
public Dict getOrder(Client client)
{
    string acctName = client != null ? client.AccountName : "";

    Dict replacements = new Replacement
    {
        {COMPANY_NAME, acctName}
    };
    return new Dict(replacements);
}
```

**MY TEST:**

```
public void getOrderNullTest()
{

    //Arrange

    Client myTestClient = null;

    //Act

    contentService.getOrder(myTestClient);

    //Assert

    Assert.AreEqual(string acctName, "");

}
```

Comment: Also, what is the type of `Client.AccountName`? Are you sure it's `string`, and that the property is defined by the class?

Comment: Added the error and yes I am positive it is type string thanks to visual studio ;)

Comment: Why did my question get voted down?

Comment: First, I did not down vote your question. Second, `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.` which usually leads to votes to close these as off topic.

Comment: While you eventually answered your own question and got it to work, know that the issue was that in calling the assert you have  `Assert.AreEqual(string acctName, "")` which is a syntax error, `string acctName` which is for when you are defining a method, not trying to call it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you eventually answered your own question and got it to work, know that the issue was that in calling the assert you have `Assert.AreEqual(string acctName, "")` which has a syntax error, `string acctName` which is for when you are defining a method, not trying to call it.

Here is another way you could have written it

```
//Arrange
Client myTestClient = null;
string expectedValue = String.Empty;
string expectedKey = COMPANY_NAME;

//Act
Dict result = contentService.getOrder(myTestClient);

//Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(result);

string actualValue = result[expectedKey];

Assert.IsNotNull(actualValue);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation @Nkosi but why is expectedKey in brackets in string `actualValue = result[expectedKey];` ?

Comment: The assumption was that Dict was of type Dictionary which would allow an indexed call with the key that returns the value stored at that key.

Comment: I just learned something new.  :) I thought an index call had to reference the index number to get the value, like [0] or [1]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing it like this:

```
//Arrange

Client myTestClient = null;
string expectedValue = String.Empty;
string expectedKey = COMPANY_NAME;

//Act

Dict actual = contentService.getOrder(myTestClient);

//Assert

Assert.IsTrue(actual.ContainsKey(expectedKey));
Assert.IsTrue(actual.ContainsValue(expectedValue));
```